# How to exclude libraries from different tasks in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have the following project structure:

```
/
├── project
|   └── ...
├── src
|   └── ... 
├── lib
│   ├── prod-lib.jar
|   └── test-lib.jar
└── build.sbt
```

And I need to compile with `test-lib.jar` for deploying into a testing environment and with `prod-lib.jar` for deploying into a production environment.

Both of them have the same API for accessing the things I need, so my source code does not have any problem with neither of them, but both have subtle differences on how they implement their execution in the background.

Is there a way to create a *"sbt task"* (Or maybe anything else) that can ignore one jar or the other, but in both perform the `assembly` task anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your jars in different folders and set `unmanagedBase` key in `Compile` and `Test` scopes correspondingly:

```
> set unmanagedBase in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "lib-compile"
> show compile:assembly::unmanagedBase
[info] /project/foo/lib-compile
> set unmanagedBase in Test := baseDirectory.value / "lib-test"
> show test:assembly::unmanagedBase
[info] /project/foo/lib-test
```

But don't forget to call `assembly` task in the corresponding scope then (`compile:assembly` or `test:assembly`), because in `Global` it's still the default:

```
> show assembly::unmanagedBase
[info] /project/foo/lib
```

Comment: But the problem I have is that I need a fatjar (Generated with `assembly`) with the same sources under `src`, but with different `unmanagedBase` dependencies.

I was thinking about creating two tasks `assembly-dev` and `assembly-prod` that can include those different `unmanagedBase` each, with the rest of configurations remaining equal.

Comment: Sorry I missed that from your question. The problem is that you cannot override a setting in a task.